# Unity 2d overlapped semi-transparent objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, graph

I'm making graphs in unity and i make the lines of the graph with rectangles and circles:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze3iQ.png)
But they are very ugly because the circles and squares are stranparent and overlap themselves.

So I decided not to make it transparent[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecvNy.png)
but i wonder if it there is a way to make it transparent without making it ugly

i hope you understood my english cause i'm french!

Answer (score 0):

Inside Unity you can change alpha value of colors to make them transparent :

[image]

[image]

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem at all, just look at the image that i've posted to understand

Comment: i already knew that

Answer (score 0):

Using LineRenderer instead of sprites of squares and circles would probably fix this. So if this problem is still relevant, I'd recommend looking into Line Renderers (though I doubt it lol).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).